# How can remove the laravel logo from the email template in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, email

I want to remove the laravel logo from the email template. I am used to markdown mailable class.

Comment: Please take a look at the official documentation:  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#customizing-the-components

Comment: @Aless55 Ok thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to publish the mail package’s resources.

you can use:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

You should check the laravel mail document better:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail